# Update a store property

Tags: redux

I am getting a response from an API as below:

```
{
    "results": {
        "6": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "akkha madrasi mirchi1",
        },
        "7": {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "almonds",
        },
        "8": {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "alu1",
        }
    }
}
```

I am storing `response.results` in results reducer store {} so that I can access `results` as `store.results`. I want to modify an object inside the `results`. The API only returns the updated object. Now I want to update  `id: 6` in store.results.

```
{
    "results": {
        "6": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Modified akkha madrasi mirchi1",
        }
    }
}
```

If I do this in the `results` reducer:

```
[...state,action.response]
```

will the object with key `6` replace the object with matching keys?

I am expecting state to be (note name changed to `Modified akkha madrasi mirchi1` for `id: 6`):

```
"results": {
    "6": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Modified akkha madrasi mirchi1",
    },
    "7": {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "almonds",
    },
    "8": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "alu1",
    }
}
```

I want objects to be updated even if they are nested. Just match the key and keep on replacing.

Comment: and what is your question exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I do this in the results reducer:
>
> ```
> [...state,action.response]
> ```
>
> will the object with key 6 replace the object with matching keys?

No. This is what you might use if your state was an array, but from the information you've given it's an object (all of `results` is an object with ids as keys).

What you're probably looking for is something like this:

```
return {
  ...state,
  ...action.response.results
}
```

This will create a shallow copy of the state, preserving the object references for each result item (more efficient than doing a deep copy if you don't need to). It will then overwrite the previous `id: 6` with whatever is in `response.results`.

Couple of things to remember about this:

1. It assumes you have object spread available. If not, `Object.assign({}, state, action.response.results)` will have the same effect but (IMHO) is not as clear.
2. Whatever is returned from the server will *entirely replace* whatever you already had in `id: 6`. That means if you were tracking various bits of state in the client for that id, or the server doesn't return everything you need, you might get some unexpected results.

```js
const state = {
  6: {
    id: 6,
    name: 'akkha madrasi mirchi1'
  },
  7: {
    id: 7,
    name: 'almonds'
  },
  8: {
    id: 8,
    name: 'alu1'
  }
}
const response = {
  results: {
    6: {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Modified akkha madrasi mirchi1'
    }
  }
}

console.log({
  ...state,
  ...response.results
})
```

Just for completeness, here's how you'd reduce it if you had the nested structure as described in comment thread:

```js
const state = {
  results: {
    6: {
      id: 6,
      name: 'akkha madrasi mirchi1'
    },
    7: {
      id: 7,
      name: 'almonds'
    },
    8: {
      id: 8,
      name: 'alu1'
    }
  }
}
const response = {
  results: {
    6: {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Modified akkha madrasi mirchi1'
    }
  }
}

console.log({
  ...state,
  results: {
    ...state.results,
    ...response.results
  }
})
```

Comment: That will replace everything in the results.

Comment: No it won't. I am assuming that `state` is just the `results` portion of the Redux store... in which case, it will overwrite only `id: 6`. This would be normal for a `combineReducers`-type arrangement, and you mentioned you were speaking specifically of the `results` reducer.

Comment: its the results reducer but the object i am storing is along with the results. `state = {results: {results:{1: {obj},2:{obj},3:{obj} } }, ....}`. Its not `state = {results: {1: {obj},2:{obj},3:{obj}, .... }` which is what you are mentioning. The reason is i want to know how to update an object nested inside another object. One option i has is to use normalizr but that looks a lot or which i should have implemented from the beginning.

Comment: So it's the reducer for your entire store? Normally using `combineReducers` you'd have a separate object (or array) for each 'chunk' of the reducer, and that becomes `state`.

Comment: Ok i have updated the comment assuming i am using combinedreducer for the sate. then the object is nested iniside two results.

Comment: Breaking up the reducers to deal with discrete parts of the store definitely helps you reason about each individual part, without trying to hold it all in your head at once. normalizr helps too :)

Comment: Added one more demo to show how it'd look if you were reducing to that nested structure.

Comment: Its not updating that particular id, instead its adding a new object

Comment: Yes, as I said in the answer, the object with the id will be replaced (but the references to the other ids are retained) so you need to make sure any state you can't do without is persisted, or else merge the objects in some more detailed way. This is getting pretty long for a comment thread so we'd better bring it to a halt :)

Comment: its working i checked it again. thank you, this solution is quite straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that state is:

```
{
    "6": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "akkha madrasi mirchi1"
    },
    "7": {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "almonds"
    },
    "8": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "alu1"
    }
}
```

and you want to update with the following:

```
const obj = {
  "6": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Modified akkha madrasi mirchi1"
   }
};
```

Then the following will do it:

```
state = Object.assign( {}, state, obj);
```

Comment: But its nested in the results.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it using the immutability-helper

this is my action creator:

```
export function itemupdate(response) {
    return {
        type: 'ITEMS_UPDATE_DATA_SUCCESS',
        idx: Object.keys(response.results)[0],
        obj: response.results[Object.keys(response.results)[0]]
    }
}
```

This is how i replace that particular id object in the results.

```
export function data(state = {}, action) {
    case 'ITEMS_UPDATE_DATA_SUCCESS':
        return update(state,{results: {[action.idx]: {$set: action.obj} }})
    default:
        return state;
    }
```